# Decorators for functions

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, decorator, ecma

As I see, decorators usually can be used with classes and methods inside classes. Is there a way to use decorators with regular functions like in code below:

```
@myDecorator()
function someFunction() {
  // do something
}

someFunction(); // running the function with the decorator.
```

Answer (score 3):

Not with [the current proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators). Decorating stand-alone functions, object initializers and their contents, or other things may well be follow-on proposals, but the current proposal only allows decorating classes and their contents.

Answer (score 2):

Decorators are not supported on functions as per the current [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators)

You can acrive a similar result using a simple function call:

```
function myDecorator<Args extends any[], R>(fn: (...a: Args)=> R): (...a:Args) =>R {
    return function (...a: Args) {
        console.log("Calling");
        return fn(...a);
    } 
}
const someFunction = myDecorator(function () {
    console.log("Call");
});

someFunction();
```

Comment: Yeah. I thought about that. But it looks too verbose :(

Comment: @BogdanSurai Yeah, it's a bit more verbose but still readable I think :)

Comment: @BogdanSurai - You can make it a bit less verbose if you do it as `function target() { /*...*/ } target = myDecorator(target);` (I'd do what Titian does above instead, not least because of the time gap due to hoisting; just pointing out the option). But yes, explicit syntax will help this when it gets here.